# Привязка домена к динамическому IP

Tags: ip, домен, ubuntu

Собственно есть OS Ubuntu, интернет с динамическим IP и домен, который нужно привязать к веб-серверу.Возможно ли как то это сделать?Быть может прокси, или что то еще?Если возможно, то как и что для этого нужно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно в домене прописать CNAME на какой-либо DynamicDNS сервис, а на Ubuntu запустить DynDNS клиент.